# How do I change the shower tap?

Tags: shower, leak

I need to fix the leak from the shower head but I don't know how to open the tap. Could anyone please assist?

[image]

Comment: On the top knob there seems to be a small hole.  This hole might be to use an allen key to remove a lock/set screw.  Knob should then come off.

Comment: Thank you for the help, crip. I thought there's something about the small hole but none of my screwdrivers can do anything about it . I'll buy a set of Allen keys from Amazon, which takes a few days to arrive.

Comment: Before you buy, should try to use a flashlight and see the shape.  Most are six sided hex shape, but better to check for right type incase the maker used something different.

Comment: Have you tried to address the leak at the shower head? Is it clogged, perhaps, from hard water deposits? Does everything else about the shower head threads look normal? Was teflon tape used to screw on the shower head? That alone could cause a leak. (Absence of Teflon tape or pipe dope). Leave the valve alone (you call it a "tap") until you've addressed the above questions.

Comment: Hi DAS. I've had to really turn the knob hard until the leak stops. Made me think that it should be the washer from the valve that needs replacing...